# How to setup HTTP Headers (Authorization) on REST POST method in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho

I need to setup HTTP headers (Authorization) on the REST Client (Post method) in Pentaho. But whenever I supply `Field=Authorization` and `Name=Basic ASDFjfhnsdfjjfh34jbsdaAKJFasdfioHJ=` in the headers section, it is not working properly.

Below is the error message

```
Error finding field [Authorization] in incoming stream!
```

Can some one please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the trick. Pass on the Authorization header as a parameter to the REST Client. Then use that variable inside the Headers field. We cannot provide it directly since it expects them to be sent forward rather than initiated within the REST Client.

Comment: this is an insane oversight to some basic http functionality

Answer (score 2):

In order to accomplish this and pass authentication to the header, you have to add the Authorization request header to the "Generate Rows" step (which should be one of your first steps before your REST Client step) as another field. Then set the type to "String" and then the value to the actual authentication value. Then in the "REST Client" step, go to the Headers tab and add "Authorization" in BOTH the Name and Field columns for row 1, or click "Get Rows" and remove everything but header info that you need.

This could be WAY easier in my opinion but this is how you have to pass it in.

Comment: again, hacking a tool to pass http request headers in is insane - it is some one of the most basic requirements of an http client, how could it be bungled this badly

Comment: I do not disagree. Hence me thinking it could be WAY easier to do this. I spent hours trying to figure out this "hack" which should be innate in the REST Client step itself.